# Redirect http to https using multi variable passing in url gives 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i m using this in `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./feature.php
```

I want to pass my url like

```
https://example.com/variable1/variable2/variable3
```

Comment: is what you have posted your full `.htaccess` file ?

Answer (score 0):

modify your code to ...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /   
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /feature.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks for ur response but "When i use http its working" http://example.com/variable1/variable2/variable3  if i use https then only this page is not working

Comment: are you using two separate directories for `http` vs `https` ?